# Sorting a list of objects using multiple fields (Java 8)

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

Let's say I have a class `Person` that has methods `getAge()` and `getYearsOfEducation()`, both returning `int`s. Then I have another class `Employer` that has a method `getYearsOfEmployment(Person p)` for a given `Person`, also returning an `int`.

```
Employer e = new Employer();
Person p1 = new Person(26, 3) // age and years of education
Person p2 = new Person(30, 4) 
Person p3 = new Person(28, 5) // let's say that e.getYearsOfEmployment(p3) returns 10
Person p4 = new Person(28, 5) // let's say that e.getYearsOfEmployment(p4) returns 8
```

When I have a list of `Person`s (added randomly to the list), I want it sorted (1) by age, (2) by years of education, and (3) by years of employment (always least first) -- so in the above example, the final order should be `p1`, `p4`, `p3`, `p2`. It is clear to me how to sort by age and years of education, but I cannot figure out how to do the final sorting by years of employment since that is not a method of `Person`.

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(new Person[]{p1, p2, p3, p4});    
Collections.sort(persons, Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)
        .thenComparing(Person::getYearsOfEducation)
        .thenComparing(...));
```

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: If you have an `Employer e` available before that `Collections#sort` call, it would just be `.thenComparing(e::getYearsOfEmployment)`.

Comment: @Rogue Perfect, this worked. If you make this an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You can give it to @Alexander, he put the effort into a fully fleshed-out answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks anyway, you were superfast, which was exactly what I needed now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [*@Rogue* has said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318979/sorting-a-list-of-objects-using-multiple-fields-java-8#comment131205520_74318979) you need a reference to an instance of `Employer`.

In case if all `Person` instances belong to the same `Employer`, then you can use it in the *keyExtractor* function of `thenComparing()` (*alternatively, you can use* `thenComparingInt()`):

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(new Person[]{p1, p2, p3, p4});
Employer employer = // initializing the employer

Collections.sort(persons, Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)
    .thenComparing(Person::getYearsOfEducation)
    .thenComparing(employer::getYearsOfEmployment);
```

Where `employer::getYearsOfEmployment` is an equivalent of the following lambda expression:

```
person -> employer.getYearsOfEmployment(person)
```

And it should be qualified as a [Reference to an Instance Method of a Particular Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#object)